# Connecting to postgresql in compact framework for windows ce 5

Tags: postgresql, compact-framework, windows-ce

Anyone know how to connect directly to PostgreSQL from Windows CE device using c# compact framework? Tried dotConnect but express version does not support compact framework. Also tried Npgsql but still the same, no CF support.

Help...

Comment: I have read that already, from what I understand from there, you need to create a webpage in a server that will act as a bridge (correct me if I'm wrong).. I actually prefer if I can connect directly to postgreSQL.

Comment: AFAIK there you can not have a direct connection from a windows mobile device. Therefor you need a 'gateway' or bridge.

Comment: After a search of 'postgresql pocketpc' I found this http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/c4f20e170604130150y46aef60bu9db392a170da9bb@mail.gmail.com and this http://www.postgresql.org/download/products/2-drivers-and-interfaces/. Possibly Npgsql or libpqxx or other can be ported to compact framework